# Why does my mergesort code always fail when sorting the right half in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

When I try to do the merge in C++, strange errors appear.

When I input an array of length 10 and values

> [9, 8, 57, 2, 34, 21, 0, 4, 8, 6]

to sort, the first step should be to sort

> [9, 8]

Then

> [9, 8, 57]

, then it should be

> [2, 34]

As shown in the figure below, the merge method can complete the sorting of 8, 9, and 57 on the left half (as shown in the green box).
But when it comes to sorting on the right half, the program can not even display this position correctly (The original value, as shown in the red box, arr[3] and arr[4] should have been 2 and 34, but here are 6 and 4255921 that have not been entered)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLSVz.png)

And another weird thing is that the final program also can't finish outputting the sorted array.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkgjs.png)

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int times = 0;//the times to call merge function 

void merge(int* arr, int left, int mid, int right)
{
    times++;
    cout << "the " << times <<" times to call merge function" << endl;
    
    //use a temp array to store the sorted array
    int length =right-left+1;
    int tmparr[length] = {0};
    
    int i = left, j = mid+1;
    int k;
    for(k = 0; i <= mid && j <= right; k++)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[j])
            tmparr[k] = arr[i++]; 
        else
            tmparr[k] = arr[j++];
    }
    
    while(i <= mid)//if left half is not compeleted
        tmparr[k++] = arr[i++]; 
    while(j <= right)//else right half is not compelted
        tmparr[k++] = arr[j++];
    
    //cout to show the sorted array fragment    
    cout << "The array values between "<< left << " and " << right << "are currently:" << endl; 
    for(k = 0, i = left; k < length; k++)
    {
        arr[i++] = tmparr[k];   
        cout << arr[i - 1] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


void sort(int* a, int l, int r)
{
    //when there is more than one element
    if(l < r)
    {
        int mid = (l + r)/2;
        sort(&a[l], l, mid); //sort the left half
        sort(&a[mid+1], mid+1, r);//sort the right half
        merge(&a[l], l, mid, r);
        
        cout << "Complete the sorting between " << l <<" and " << r << endl << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    //enter array
    int n;
    cout << "enter the length of array:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "enter the values of elements:" << endl; 
    int a[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        cin >> a[i];
    //check the original array
    cout << "the original array :" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
        cout << a[i] << ' ';
    cout << endl;
    //mergesort
    sort(a, 0, n-1);
    //show the result
    cout << "the results after mergersort:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        cout << a[i] <<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell me how to solve this weird but amazing problem o_o? thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The array argument passed from the `sort()` function is wrong.

Writing like this:

```cpp
sort(&a[l], l, mid);
```

You are firstly moving `l` elements ahead in `&a[l]`, then moving `l` elements ahead again via the 2nd argument `l`.

Instead of this:

```cpp
        sort(&a[l], l, mid); //sort the left half
        sort(&a[mid+1], mid+1, r);//sort the right half
        merge(&a[l], l, mid, r);
```

You should write like this:

```cpp
        sort(a, l, mid); //sort the left half
        sort(a, mid+1, r);//sort the right half
        merge(a, l, mid, r);
```

Comment: You are really amazing! This result has been bothering me for a long time, and the problem turned out to be here! I can now run it and get the correct result, thhhhhhhhhhank you~v~